# datatool - How can you load database from .csv-file with values tokenized with same catcode-settings as are used by \verb|...|?

Tags: datatool, catcodes

I plan to use the package datatool for loading a .csv-file as database:

```
\DTLloaddb[<options>]{<db name>}{<filename>}
```

How to achieve tokenizing values of that database under the same catcode-settings as are used by `\verb|...|`?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it is sufficient to switch to the desired catcode-régime right before calling `\DTLloaddb`.
You may need to call `\DTLsetdelimiter` and/or `\DTLsetseparator` for adjusting delimiter and separator to the desired catcode-régime, too.

**!!! But I don't know whether such catcode-changes affect the sorting-algorithms or whatsoever other functionality of the datatool-package. !!!**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
ColumnA,ColumnB
\TeX,\LaTeX
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{testdatabase}{test.csv}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\myDTLloaddbwrapper[2]{%
  \begingroup  
  % Let's switch to verbatim-catcode-régime:
  \let\do\@makeother  \dospecials
  % ( You may need to call \DTLsetdelimiter and/or \DTLsetseparator with an argument
  %   that also got tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime.
  %   I don't do it here because category-codes of default-delimiter " and 
  %   default-separator , are not affected when switching to verbatim-catcode-régime. ) 
  \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\myDTLloaddbwrapper{testdatabaseB}{test.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{testdatabase}{\ColA=ColumnA, \ColB=ColumnB}{%
  \par\noindent\ColA{} and \ColB.
}%


\DTLforeach{testdatabaseB}{\ColA=ColumnA, \ColB=ColumnB}{%
  \par\noindent{\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\ColA{} and \ColB}.
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The possibility of specifying the desired catcode-régime for each column (and probably post-processing-routines to be applied to the values of a column) when loading a .csv-file via `\DTLloaddb` would be extremely nice.)

In case you just wish to disable some of the special characters, the command `\DTLloadrawdb` might be the right tool.

More information at

https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/loadcsv.shtml

> `\DTLloadrawdb[⟨options⟩]{⟨db-name⟩}{⟨filename⟩}`
>
> This is like `\DTLloaddb` except that it performs a substitution on
> nine of the ten special characters. (The backslash always retains its
> special state.) The mappings are listed in Table 2.1.
>
> ```
> Table 2.1: Special character mappings used by \DTLloadrawdb
>
> Character Mapping
>
> %          \%
> $          \$
> &          \&
> #          \#
> _          \_
> {          \{
> }          \}
> ~          \textasciitilde
> ^          \textasciicircum
> ```